# MacBook cannot connect to non-SSL websites

Tags: macos, network, macbook-pro, web-browsing, ssl

I have the late 2013 MBP 15″ with Retina and recently I've been unable to connect to websites not using SSL with either Firefox or Safari. This includes other applications that use HTTP such as the Twitter official app and the App Store.

These sites work fine using the Tor Browser Bundle, and other machines on my network seem to have no issues. This problem persists across other networks and ISPs (Tested with Verizon fios and Time Warner cable.)

If I attempt to traceroute an unencrypted site (for example, honda.com) it ceases to progress after hitting *vlan38.dca2a-fdisa-sw2-msfc1.netsrv.digex.net (164.109.3.146)*

Edit: Problem persists with both Root account and freshly created non-administrative user account.

Edit2: All proxy settings have been disabled, both in wireless settings and Firefox. Problem persists.

Comment: Does this problem occur on this laptop with a test user account?

Comment: Check your network settings for a HTTP proxy.

Comment: Does this problem impact other devices on the same network?  Does the problem persist with this device when it is on a different network?

Comment: @AllInOne I noted in my question that the problem is isolated to this machine and persists across networks and ISPs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed this problem awhile ago on a customer's machine, in that instance I believe it was an issue with the WebKit framework.

I'm assuming you don't have access to an external bootable drive, (if you did, boot off it and test).  Try booting to your Recovery HD and see if "Get Help Online" works.  If it does we know the problem resides in your OS, I recommend backing up your machine and performing an install of your OS, note a clean install should not be necessary unless an archive install fails to resolve the problem.

Comment: the "Get Help Online" in recovery functions properly. However I'm not sure what you mean by an "archive install"

Comment: Archive install refers to leaving applications and user data on the machine and reinstalling the OS only.  In previous versions of Mac OS all files on the system would be archived into a folder called "Previous System" and user data would have to be moved out post install, this behavior doesn't happen with any modern Mac OS however, but some techs still refer to a non-clean install as an "archive install".

Comment: An archive install worked. Thank you for the help.